# Trying to console.log last 10 tweets using node

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm trying to get the last 10 tweets from my twitter. I have my keys in a separate file and require it at top. I followed the steps that are on npm twitter and everything seem to look right. When I run it in my terminal I don't get any error or anything. Not too sure what is going on. This is the first time using the twitter api and still learning about node. Not sure is this is a problem but I notice that with I do "var client = new Twitter(twitterKeys);" the word Twitter is white and doesn't turn another color like when calling on a method.

```
 var keys = require("./key.js");

 var Twitter = require('twitter');
 var twitterKeys = keys.twitterKeys;    

 function twitter() {
     var client = new Twitter(twitterKeys);

     var params = {screen_name: 'stacysareas', count: 10};

     client.get('statuses/user_timeline/', params, function(error, 
     tweets, response) {
         if (!error) {
         console.log(tweets);
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: try `console.log(error)` to see if you are getting an error (right before your `if` statement). You can also add some text to `console.log(tweets)` so you can know if it is called but `tweets` is empty (e.g, `console.log('my tweets', tweets)`. And what is response supposed to be? You could `console.log(response)` too although it may be a lengthy mess if it is a full http response.

Comment: It gives me -- { code: 89, message: 'Invalid or expired token.' } -- which is strange because I just got all the tokens today and I have double check to see if everything is the same multiple times.

Comment: hmmm, then console.log your twitterKeys to confirm they are what you expect them to be. If they are, try regenerating new keys.

Comment: It comes up as undefined. I'm going to regenerate the keys and see what happens.

Comment: well, if `twitterKeys` are undefined, they you need to check `keys` (`console.log(keys)`)-- if `keys` is undefined, your `require` path is likely wrong -- otherwise maybe `keys.twitterKeys` is not set properly in `key.js` or is not exported

Comment: Ah -- change `var keys = require('"./key.js")` to `var keys = require('"./key")` (delete the `.js`)

Comment: Why wouldn't I need the .js? Wouldn't it not know what file to look for?

Comment: hmm, I guess it is optional -- sorry -- I always leave off the `.js`, but just tested and confirmed `require` doesn't care if it is there or not -- you should focus on finding out why `twitterKeys` is undefined

Comment: Yeah, I think my keys file isn't set up properly. Keys brings up my Spotify keys and not the Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is here:

```
if (!error) {
   console.log(tweets);
}
```

try this instead:

```
if (error) {
   throw error;
} else {
   console.log(tweets);
}
```

I believe that no matter what, something is coming back as the error argument.  So when you say if !error, that condition never fires.  Handle the error if it happens, and if not do something with the tweets

Comment: Yes, that makes sense I just used what the docs gave me. I did change it and I get this:  -- { code: 89, message: 'Invalid or expired token.' } --

Answer (score 0):

It return very well, are you put it in get/post method of node? You need install Express as well

```
router.get('/twitter', function (req, res, next){

var params = {screen_name: 'stacysareas', count: 10};
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(tweets);
    }
});})

var client = new Twitter({
consumer_key: 'xxx',
consumer_secret: 'yyyy',
access_token_key: 'zzzz',
access_token_secret: 'zz'});
```

Make sure you got right token from: https://apps.twitter.com/app/1466387/keys

Comment: Yeah, everything it correct. I able to get them now I getting this --- [ { code: 215, message: 'Bad Authentication data.' } ] so I'll looking at the docs to see how to fix this.